# JavaScript - jQuery on click doesn't work correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Sweetalert plugin in use. I made there an table with an X button, after you click button then the sweetalert pops up with table content and the X's. So I made code, if you click on X it will delete it from the table, but it won't work for me.. If I copied the SweetAlert HTML code to JSFiddle and the same deleting code, then it was working.

```
$('.sweet-container').on('click', 'tr td span', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: any errors in the console? also try to console.log $(this).closest('tr') and check its the correct element

Comment: Nope, nothing in console apparently.

Comment: **"Doesn't work"** doesn't showing an issue but a complain for me.

Comment: I have no idea where the issue is.. That's the problem. If code works in one place and doesn't in other

Answer (score 0):

I came across with the similar problem in the past.
Your trigger is created before the .sweet-container is created in DOM
You can use http://api.jquery.com/delegate/.

```
$('.sweet-container').delegate('tr td span', 'click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

Comment: Really interesting :/ In JSFiddle it works, in site nope.

Comment: replacing current standard `.on()` method with depreciated `.delegate()` version is not a good idea.

Comment: why not? that eliminates the problem of not having the elments in the DOM and event still working